# How to customise android pip mode like whatsapp does?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Could anyone tell me how to open `pip` window like WhatsApp opens YouTube and Instagram pip window? I am currently able to make a `pip` mode activity but unlike WhatsApp, my pip mode opens in 3 default states (small size window, half screen size window and full screen size window) and I have no clue how to open it. 
In its 2nd state eliminating the 1st state WhatsApp.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried so far (some code etc.)?

Comment: I followed this page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture instruction as well as go through this GitHub project https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PictureInPicture/blob/master/README.md but I am unable to identify how to open pip mode in its 2nd state like whats app open its youtube video in pip mode.